# Add a Superfish drop menu to a website

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

After installing superfish on my Drupal 7 site, I don't know what to do next. I searched the web and read some brief tutorials, i was told to load the css and js files to my theme. I got Superfish library from https://github.com/mehrpadin/Superfish-for-Drupal, it contains a sample which is used as an example. Could you give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use any modules when I wanna do that, you can do that by adding just 2 javascript to your theme's .info file. Make sure to place superfish.js before main.js.

```
scripts[] = js/superfish.js
scripts[] = js/main.js
```

Add the following code to main.js file:

```
jQuery(function()
{
    jQuery('div#menu_wrapper ul.menu').superfish(
    { 
        delay       : 500,                             // one second delay on mouseout 
        animation   : {opacity:'show',height:'show'},  // fade-in and slide-down animation 
        speed       : 'fast',                          // faster animation speed 
        autoArrows  : false,                           // disable generation of arrow mark-up 
        dropShadows : true                             //  drop shadows 
    });
});
```

I dunno a place to download to download the superfish library, but I have it minified in my website. http://abklimo.website-chef.com/sites/all/themes/abklimonew/js/superfish.js

Hope this helps,

Muhammad

Answer (score 0):

The [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) module allows you to create such menus using Superfish. I recommend that you check it out. I am unsure if it uses the same wrapper that you have chosen, but it works reasonably well and comes with documentation.

Good luck!